# What is admin-dashboard component in wso2 am such as version 1.10.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I came across this admin-dashboard component and am just curious what it is or what it can do.

It is mentioned in WSO2 documentation related to workflow customization. I did not find any related pages dedicated to this component. What is it, and what is designed for, or what it can do?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its created for the administrative tasks and few other tasks. You can do the following using the admin dashboard.

1. There are several activities related to api store which we can configure workflows. For example, if someone wants to sign up to your store, you can submit it for the store owner's approval. Other places where you can configure work flows are application creation and api subscription. Such pending approval appear in the admin dashboard where the admin can approve or reject them.
2. You can upload customized themese for api store
3. This also provides a UI for adding and editing throttling tiers.

In the next releases this will get more such functionalities added.

Comment: Noted for future use. Thanks. Any URL links for this component?

Comment: Looks like there is no dedicated page for the admin dashboard in docs. But, its mentioned whenever its needed to get something done. For example, see this doc on adding custom tiers.https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Adding+a+new+Throttling+Tier#AddinganewThrottlingTier-UsingtheAdminDashboard